# perl awk OR sed, search between two timestamps

Tags: perl, time, awk, sed, timestamp

I have a file with following sample text. (The actual text is huge).

```
2014/05/08-19:15:44.544824-<String1>
2014/05/08-19:21:54.544824-<String2>
2014/05/08-19:34:59.564461-<String3>
```

I have to extract data between two timestamps like 19:15:00 - 19:20:00 and so on until the eof. I have tried using sed & awk, but the problem is that at certain points they give out every thing. (e.g they'd give out everything from 19:15:00 --> EOF). The commands which i used were

```
awk '/19:15:00/,/19:20:00/' InputFile
```

and

```
sed '/19:15:00/,/19:20:00/p' Inputfile.
```

Any ideas as how to do it in perl or sed & awk, which might actually work ? Is the wrong output has something to do with the format of the time stamps ? (just thinking)

PS. I am using the following code to make time stamps. (is it possible because of localtime function this is happening ?

```
$curr = timelocal(0, 0, 0, (split /\//, $ARGV[0])[1], (split /\//, $ARGV[0])[0]-1, (split /\//, $ARGV[0])[-1]);
$currentTime = strftime "%H:%M:%S", localtime($curr);
```

Comment: I realise that your data is relatively large, but there is no reason to give just a three-line sample. There is nothing useful for us to test our solutions with, and you haven't indicated, for instance, whether the data is already sorted in order of ascending time. I don't know what the limit is, but you are allowed to post a substantial number of code lines. If the size of the sample would interfere with the intelligibility of the post then is it reduced to a scrolling block, so please don't stint on the size of your example data

Comment: Thanks, thats a good suggestion, I ll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a perl one-liner.  Capture the time and then just compare.

```
perl -ne '$t = /(\d+:[\d:.]+)/ ? $1 : undef; 
    print if $t ge "19:15:00" && $t le "19:20:00";' file.txt
```

Comment: Error ........  perl -ne '$t = /(\d+:[\d:.]+)/ ? $1 : undef;  print if $t ge '19:15:00' && $t le '19:20:00';' /tmp/Output.txt
syntax error at -e line 1, near "19:"

Comment: @user3195304 Yeah, just need to use a different delimiter for the strings inside the eval.  updated.

Comment: I originally single quoted the `'19:15:00'` string.  That won't work without escaping because the eval is enclosed in single quotes `-e '...'`.  The easiest solution is to just use double quotes instead `"19:15:00"`, which I've updated in the post.  Alternatively, could also use `q{19:15:00}` which is sometimes a nice option in case one is interchanging a one liner between windows and unix environments.

Comment: @Miller: What `eval`? The `-e` option doesn't perform an `eval`

Comment: @Miller: Ah I see what you mean: you originally used `-e '...'` with single-quoted embedded strings. I think it's dangerous to think of the `-e` option as an `eval` as the two are very different, for instance any string passed to `eval` won't crash the program, but the `-e` parameter *must* compile and execute cleanly. I prefer to think of `-e` as `--execute`

Answer (score 2):

The awk and sed commands you show above won't work because they're doing pattern matching -- they're not comparing timestamps to each other in chronological terms (ie, if it doesn't see an exact 19:20:00 string, it will continue to the end even if it sees a 19:21:00 along the way).

You could probably do it in perl using something similar to the two lines you show at the end where you're generating the timestamps, but in reverse to parse them, convert them to a time object and compare their values.

Comment: Great info. now i understand. I was trying for perl flip flop, or a perl one liner. But failing uptil now ! Any ideas there ?

Answer (score 1):

It may not be obvious, but a date/time representation that has fixed-width fields in decreasing order of magnitude (like [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S`) can simply be compared as strings, so `'19:21:54.544824' gt '19:20'` is *true*, while `19:15:44.544824 lt '19:15'` is *false*.

That means you can just use `split` to extract the field and do literal comparisons, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  my $time = (split /-/)[1];
  print if $time ge '19:15' and $time le '19:20';
}

__DATA__
2014/05/08-19:15:44.544824-<String1>
2014/05/08-19:21:54.544824-<String2>
2014/05/08-19:34:59.564461-<String3>
```

**output**

```
2014/05/08-19:15:44.544824-<String1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why all the complexity?

```
$ awk -F'[-.]' '"19:15:00"<=$2 && $2<="19:20:00"' file
2014/05/08-19:15:44.544824-<String1>
```

or less readably but more efficiently if the file is sorted:

```
$ awk -F'[-.]' '$2>"19:20:00"{exit} $2>="19:15:00"' file
2014/05/08-19:15:44.544824-<String1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
awk '{gsub(/:/,X,$2)}$2>=191500&&$2<=192000' FS="[-.]" file
```