# Sed extract section of log file with timestamp boundaries

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a selection of log files containing amongst other things time stamps.

Fwiw format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.sss` (ie milliseconds granularity but no further)

Happily for me I can reasonably expect these timestamps to be both sorted chronologically AND unique.

However I am running into issues extracting the portion of the log file falling between two timestamps.

first timestamp in my file is `21:27:57.545`
last timestamp in my file is `21:28:45.631`

Syntax I am using is e.g.

```
sed -n '/21:28:10*/,/21:28:22*/p'
```

This is yielding some odd results (I am sure user error)

start time of `21:28:10*` gives me timestamps starting at `21:28:10.043` (so far so good as prior was `21:28:09.484` so it is starting in the right place)

however start time of `21:28:09*` gives me timestamps starting at `21:28:00.003`

end time equally odd. end time of `21:28:22*` yields timestamps up to and including `21:28:20.050`, however I know for a fact that there timestamps after that as follows;

```
2017-05-10 21:28:21.278, 901
2017-05-10 21:28:21.303, 901
2017-05-10 21:28:21.304, 901
2017-05-10 21:28:21.483, 901
2017-05-10 21:28:22.448, 901
```

Therefore I am wondering if this is something to do with how sed interprets the strings - is it as text? Is there a one liner way to do what I am trying to do? Ideally I would be able to specify the start and end timestamps down to the same granularity as the actual data (ie in this case milliseconds)

TIA

Comment: Apologies - just spotted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572749/perl-awk-or-sed-search-between-two-timestamps

Comment: awk -F'[ .]' '"21:28:19" <=$2 && $2<="21:28:21"'  seems to work for seconds level precision but doesn't for milliseconds. But that is closer than I have got previously (from the other SO question that I cited).

Still looking for a millisecond precision one liner.

Comment: I am aware btw that I could in theory use awk to construct and print  milliseconds since midnight and do the boundary that way. Possibly my best option?

Comment: Do you want the line starting with 2017-05-10 21:28:22 included or excluded? If included, do you want all the following lines starting with 2017-05-10 21:28:22 included, too? Please provide longer sample input, more lines with 22 and state whether they should be in the output.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.*` instead of `*`.

The RE `21:28:10*` would match strings starting with `21:28:1` which can be followed by *zero or more* `0` chars.

Comment: Thanks. That works at second granularity but can't replicate with the milliseconds included as I suspect the decimal between seconds and millis interferes. I tried escaping it e.g,.



sed -n '/21:27:58\.500.*/,/21:27:59\.500.*/p'  infile.csv > outfile.csv



But it didn't print anything

Comment: plz show your `infile.csv` or no one can figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get really crazy:

```
#!/bin/bash
T1="$(date -d '2017-05-10 21:28:21' +'%s').300" # your start time
T2="$(date -d '2017-05-10 21:28:21' +'%s').400" # your end time
while read L 
do 
    D="$(echo $L | cut -c1-19)" # assuming line starts with timestamp
    T=$(date -d "$D" +'%s')
    T="${T}.$(echo $L | cut -c21-23)" 
    if [ $(echo $T'>'$T1 | bc -l) == 1 ] && [ $(echo $T'<'$T2 | bc -l) == 1 ]
    then
        echo "HIT: $L"
    else
        echo "NO!: $L"
    fi
done < your_log_file
```