# Extract logs between two timestamps

Tags: unix, awk

I'm trying to extract all logs between two time-stamps. Some lines may not have the time-stamp, but I want those lines to be included - I want every line that falls under two timestamps to be included in the extracted logs.

The start time-stamp or end time-stamp may not be there in the log, but I want every line between these two timestamps to be extracted.

My log time-stamp structure looks like: `[4/1/19 9:57:05:083 EDT] blah blah`

The `awk` command I've written is fetching the lines which contain timestamp only and skipping all other lines in between.

PFB the command I've written:

```
awk -v from="11:00:38" -v to="11:50:36" '$2>=from && $2<=to && $1 == "\[4/1/19"' SystemOut.log
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [perl awk OR sed, search between two timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572749/perl-awk-or-sed-search-between-two-timestamps)

Comment: How do you handle the change in TZ due to Daylight Saving Time (like this weekend)

Comment: Our logs are in UTC - no change in TZ

Comment: [edit] your question to show a [mcve] including a few lines of concise, testable sample input (some inside, some outside of your target window) and the expected output given that input so we can help you. See [ask] if that's not clear. Is 4/1 April 1st or Jan 4th?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `from_time_string` and `to_time_string` are match patterns for your timestamps, this will print all lines between instances of `from_time_string` and `to_time_string`:

```
awk '/from_time_string/{flag=1}/to_time_string/{flag=0;}flag' SystemOut.log
```

Comment: May I know if you are suggesting :  awk '/11:00:38/{flag=1}/11:50:36/{flag=0;}flag' SystemOut.log ? - This is not giving me any output

Comment: This will not work if the Timestrings you are suggesting are not in the log-file!

Comment: I will need between the time range , even if the time string doesn't match in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to start - create an alphanumerically sortable/comparable timestamp from your input data:

```
$ awk -F'[[/: ]' '{cur = sprintf("20%02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d:%03d", $4,$2,$3,$5,$6,$7,$8); print cur, $0}' file
2019/04/01 09:57:05:083 [4/1/19 9:57:05:083 EDT] blah blah
```

Now just compare that to your from and to values:

```
$ awk -v from='2019/04/01 09:45' -v to='2019/04/01 10:20:13' -F'[[/: ]' '
    { cur = sprintf("20%02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d:%03d", $4,$2,$3,$5,$6,$7,$8) }
    (cur >= from) && (cur <= to)
' file
[4/1/19 9:57:05:083 EDT] blah blah
```

If you don't care about the date then just don't include it when creating `cur` and specifying `from` and `to`.